# Show variable on frontend based on if checkbox is checked

Tags: php

I hope I can explain this right but the image should make it clear (hopefully).

In the admin side of my site, I have different fields for products, but I do not want the fields shown to the frontend user if the show checkbox isn't checked. As seen in my image below.

Now my issue I am not getting is should I have a row name for every checkbox or can I use just one like show.

simplified can I use something like this

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3">Sales Price</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>" class="form-control" />
  </div> <!-- /.col -->
<input type="checkbox" value="1" <?php echo ($row['show'] == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> name="show">
</div> <!-- /.form-group -->
```

or do I have to use something like this

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3">Sales Price</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>" class="form-control" />
  </div> <!-- /.col -->
<input type="checkbox" value="1" <?php echo ($row['showprice'] == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> name="showprice">
</div> <!-- /.form-group -->
```

Here is what I am after using an image.

[image]

As for making the content show on the frontend Here is the code for that. This is set up now to NOT show if the data is missing. (I haven't set it up to show about the checkboxes until I figure out what to use)

```
<?php if (isset($model) && !empty($model)) : ?>
 <li class="element element-text">
  <strong>Model #: </strong>
   <?php echo $model;?>
 </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I thought about using something like this, but again I am not sure if I can use a single checkbox (show) for all the variables.

```
<div style="display:<?= ($offer === 1) ? 'block' : 'none'; ?>"></div>
```

Again, I hope I explained this good enough and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use a single checkbox or multiple. It just depends on whether you want to turn display on/off individually for inputs or just as a group.

Comment: I need them to be individually.

Comment: Then you would need one checkbox for each input. The name of the checkbox would need to be something you could tie to a particular input. Then, when you go to display the field, check the corresponding checkbox to decide how to handle it.

Comment: I appreciate it, Can you tell me how I would have them to display? Would my example above with the div work?

Comment: Yes, but it might be simpler to add a new test to your if so that the <li> is not created if the box is not checked. For example: if ($isChecked && isset($model) && !empty($model)) where $isChecked is set based on whether the corresponding checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: I appreciate and I am sorry for all the questions. Would the $isChecked have the same name as the model? For example:  <input type="text" name="model" value="" class="form-control" />
                  <input type="checkbox" name="model">

Comment: Yes, you would probably want a variable name tied to the input/checkbox combo to which it applied.

Comment: Last question, would I need to add anything to the database structure to handle the checkbox?

Comment: No, since it's just used to decide what to do with the field. But you would need to save it on the Admin side as part of the settings.

Comment: I tried just adding it but the items wouldn't display. Trying to find another way of doing it. This might be a little over my head as of right now. Still trying to learn how it all works. Very much appreciate your time.